# Append and remove child elements in javascript if radio button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html

I am writing code to `select` a database using which I can show which type of query should be run. I am adding queries in select tag using dynamic `append()` and if I change the radio button choice select options should be changed and every time I click the radio button the previous select tag should be removed. I have written the code but it's not even appending the select child node.Please help
Thank you.

```
var container = document.getElementById("container");
            if(db == "user")
            {
                if(bookq==null)
                {
                    bookq = document.getElementById ("query2");
                    bookq.parentNode.removeChild (bookq);
                }
                var array = ["Show Database","Delete Record"];
                var selectList = document.createElement("select");
                selectList.id = "query1";
                container.appendChild(selectList);
                for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) 
                {
                    var option = document.createElement("option");
                    option.value = array[i];
                    option.text = array[i];
                    selectList.appendChild(option);
                }
                userq=null;
            }
            else 
            {
                if(userq==null)
                {
                    userq = document.getElementById ("query1");
                    userq.parentNode.removeChild (userq);
                }
                var array = ["Show Database","Delete Record","Insert Record"];
                var selectList = document.createElement("select");
                selectList.id = "query2";
                container.appendChild(selectList);
                for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) 
                {
                    var option = document.createElement("option");
                    option.value = array[i];
                    option.text = array[i];
                    selectList.appendChild(option);
                }
                bookq=null;
            }
```

Comment: Silly question but, do you have the id='container' element somewhere? I can't tell without your html.

Comment: Another thing to consider is, if you have this block of code in onready function, I don't see any issue why it wouldn't append it. But if not, and you have this code in between head, then your DOM objects are not ready when this runs. So there is no id='container' on your page yet.

Comment: f12 in your browser while your app is running and a little debugging might help you figure out what is going here .. just sayin'

Comment: Yes i have div element with id=container and i have written the function in head

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your code in between

```
window.onload = function(){
  //  your code goes here
}
```

This will assure that DOM objects are loaded and ready for javascript calls.